# Building query with Oledb command to query AS400 database

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Am trying to query the AS400 database with parameterised query. Here is my code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["****"].ConnectionString;
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
{
    string sqlStr = @"SELECT CASE IsBatch WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                      FROM Batch200 
                      WHERE BatchID=LEFT(?,4) AND BatchNumber=CAST(RIGHT(?,9)AS INT)";

    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = str;
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@p1", polNumber));

    var option = command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

I tried with both the queries, none of them is working. How to resolve this issue ?

Am getting this error message:

> SQL5016: Qualified object name **** not valid.
>
> Cause . . . . . : One of the following has occurred:
>
> -- The syntax used for the qualified object name is not valid for the naming option specified.  With system naming, the qualified form of an object name is schema-name/object-name.  With SQL naming the qualified form of an object name is authorization-name.object-name.
>
> -- The syntax used for the qualified object name is not allowed. User-defined types cannot be qualified with the schema in the system naming convention on parameters and SQL variables of an SQL procedure or function.
>
> Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try the request again:
>
> -- If you want to use the SQL naming convention, verify the SQL naming option in the appropriate SQL command and qualify the object names in the form authorization-id.object-name.
>
> -- If you want to use the system naming convention, specify the system naming option in the appropriate SQL command and qualify the object names in the form schema-name/object-name.
>
> -- With the system naming convention, ensure the user-defined types specified for parameters and variables in an SQL routine can be found in the current path.

Comment: What do you mean why say "not working"?

Comment: store the connection string in a .Config file and then change this line 
`using (OleDbCommand command = con.CreateCommand())` to 
`using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlStr, con))` also look up your syntax for `CASE WHEN` you should `END as IsBatch` if the syntax is the same for example in Sql Server

Comment: @abatishchev added the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parameters. SqlStr expects two.

I think it should read something like

```
string sqlStr = @"SELECT CASE IsBatch WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                  FROM Batch200 
                  WHERE BatchID=LEFT(@BATCHID,4) AND BatchNumber=CAST(RIGHT(@BATCHNUMBER,9)AS INT)";
```

You would then add the two parameters

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@BATCHID", batchID));
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@BATCHNUMBER", batchNumber));
```